# How to change a RecyclerView item attribute programmaticaly, particularly a custom view inside the recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am doing some homework and want to do the following: my objects in a list have a value Tag. And I want to show/hide a custom view inside the `recyclerview` item layout depending on the Tag value. The idea is to use this to draw a line over the `recyclerview` items to mark them connected regardless of position with that line based on Tag value.

I used `setVisibility(View.GONE)` in previous projects and it worked on simple views, but no matter where and how I put the code, it is not working in this example.

These are the custom views in `recyclerview` item view that get inflated (the `lineTextViewTopHalf` and `lineTextViewBottomHalf` )

```xml
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.example.taskmodel.view.LineTextView
            android:id="@+id/lineTextViewTopHalf"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <com.example.taskmodel.view.LineTextView
            android:id="@+id/lineTextViewBottomHalf"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The `lineTextViewTop/BottomHalf` draws as expected

```java
public class LineTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    //constructors

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), paint);
    }
}
```

And this is from the adapter class where I am trying so get it to show/hide, but it doesn't (//where code does nothing)

```java
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ElementHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tv1.setText(elementModels.get(position).getB());
        holder.tv2.setText(String.valueOf(elementModels.get(position).getA()));
        holder.tv3.setText(String.valueOf(elementModels.get(position).getC()));

        //this code does nothing, tested to be 1
        if(elementModels.get(position).getTag().equals("1")) {
            holder.lineTextViewTopHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
```

Even when I move the code around the adapter class, I am not getting anything.

```java
class ElementHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv1;
        TextView tv2;
        TextView tv3;
        LineTextView lineTextViewTopHalf;
        LineTextView lineTextViewBottomHalf;


        public ElementHolder(@NonNull View itemView, List<ElementModel> elementModels) {

            super(itemView);

            int position = itemView.getVerticalScrollbarPosition();
            tv1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNaziv);
            tv2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPocetak);
            tv3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvKraj);
            lineTextViewTopHalf = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lineTextViewTopHalf);
            lineTextViewBottomHalf = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lineTextViewBottomHalf);


            //this code does nothing, and position is tested to be 0
            if(position == 0) {
                lineTextViewTopHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (position == elementModels.size()) {
                lineTextViewBottomHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

I was expecting the code to behave as intended and make the views show/hide, but I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated. If the syntax highlights are not showing, please forgive me, first question ever (but i did use `xml`,`java` tags when posting, will try to edit if wrong)

EDIT: I have managed to find out why it's not updating as expected. My adapter class is implementing a `callback` and I need a `Handler` to update the UI, it can't be done from a `callback` implementation.
Thank you all for contributions!

Comment: Inside `onBindViewHolder` get your position as `int realPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition()`. Aslo before this part `if(elementModels.get(position).getTag().equals("1"))`, check if `getTag` really returns "1". Maybe it never returns "1" and logic inside if never executes.

Comment: where do you settag first

Comment: @Farid from logcat ```onBindViewHolderPosition: 0
onBindViewHolderTag: 0
onBindViewHolderPosition: 1
onBindViewHolderTag: 1
onBindViewHolderPosition: 2
onBindViewHolderTag: 0
onBindViewHolderPosition: 3
onBindViewHolderTag: 1```   so what I can tell, all the parameters are right, the position increments and the tags have 2 different values. And the ```if(elementModels.get(position).getTag().equals("1"))``` still doesnt execute

Comment: @ManojPerumarath the Tag is set while populating the object list and is working, i can put the Tag value in the ```recyclerview``` row item

Answer (score 1):

In your first approached, trying to hide the lineTextView in onBindViewHolder is the correct way. It wasn't worked because somehow your condition was never matched

```
if(elementModels.get(position).getTag().equals("1"))
```

Then the code to GONE the lineTextViewTopHalf never touched

Please try with the simple condition and check if the lineTextView able to hide or not first, then check your condition again

```
if(position == 0) {
        holder.lineTextViewTopHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if ((position == 1) {
       holder.lineTextViewBottomHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ElementHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tv1.setText(elementModels.get(position).getB());
    holder.tv2.setText(String.valueOf(elementModels.get(position).getA()));
    holder.tv3.setText(String.valueOf(elementModels.get(position).getC()));


    if(position == 0) {
            holder.lineTextViewTopHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (position == elementModels.size()) {
            holder.lineTextViewBottomHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
if(position == 0) {
    holder.lineTextViewTopHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.lineTextViewBottomHalf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
} else if ((position == 1) {
   holder.lineTextViewBottomHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
   holder.lineTextViewTopHalf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
}
```

and in your onBindViewHolde method use below code

```
if(elementModels.get(position).getTag().equals("1")) {
    holder.lineTextViewTopHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.lineTextViewBottomHalf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.lineTextViewTopHalf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.lineTextViewBottomHalf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```